Idiomatic Latin for "Say the Thing"
I am looking for an idiomatic Latin phrase to say "say the thing" or "use your words," both phrases used to remind and implore people to state their needs, have difficult conversations, and set boundaries. I am looking for something short. Something with a fun meter or rhyme would be great, but less important than brevity.

dicunt rem - say the thing
dicere quod sit dictum - say that which should be said
utere verbis tuis - use your words
dic rem tuum - say your thing

Thank you!

“used to remind and implore people to state their needs” – that is to say, small children? Not sure one would say “use your words” to an adult. Utere verbis seems fine, although I don't know what Roman parents actually said to their children, if anything.

Indeed - "use your words" has a patronizing tone to it. I suspect that's what led to someone coining "say the thing" as a replacement. Thanks for your input on the Latin phrasing!
